# Receive mails through a port and extract body and headers

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to build a proxy server in between my application and my smtp server. So when my application sends an email to some email id, my proxy server should catch it and change its "TO" address to my id and then send it to smtp server so that I'll get that message in my mail. This is a different case compared to reading messages from an inbox. I dont know how to distinguish each separate mail and get mail headers and body from each mail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a general look at [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) and playing with it before asking for complete solutions.

Some other resources:

- [jGuru: Fundamentals of the JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html)
- [the JavaMail API - FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html)

Comment: You should try playing with e.g. a Gmail account, sending mails to it, receiving them, stripping/displaying the header etc. After that you can think about a solution for your application.